# $http in a service returns value in $$state in Angularjs Services

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, xmlhttprequest

i have a service written to get data from a server. the server is running locally for testing purpose. the problem that i ma facing is that the data 
is returned inside a $$state if $http is written in a Service. if same $http is written in a Controller i get the data.

$$state is not returing any data if i type res.$$state.value.dat

```
aggregate.service('someService',function ($http) 
{

        var yearlyAPI = "http://localhost:3000/api";
        var yearly =[];
        return {
        getYearlyAgg : function()
        {
            if(yearly.length!=0)
            {   
              log("Returning Stored Data For yearly Agg");
              return yearly;
            }
            else
            {

            var startDate =  "2015-08-01";
            var endDate =  "2015-08-04";

            var params = {};
            params.startDate = startDate;
            params.endDate = endDate;

            var yearData = $http.get(yearlyAPI,{
                params :params
            });

                yearly=yearData;
                log("Returning New Data For yearly Agg");
                log(yearData);
                return yearData;
            }   
        }
    };  /*Return Ends*/
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code and try this:

```
aggregate.service('someService',function ($http,$q) 
{

        var yearlyAPI = "http://localhost:3000/api";
        var yearly =[];
        return {
        getYearlyAgg : function()
        {
            if(yearly.length!=0)
            {   
              console.log("Returning Stored Data For yearly Agg");
              return $q.when(yearly); //with this you will return a promise if yearly variable contain some object
            }
            else
            {

            var startDate =  "2015-08-01";
            var endDate =  "2015-08-04";

            var params = {};
            params.startDate = startDate;
            params.endDate = endDate;

            return $http.get(yearlyAPI,{
                params :params
            }).then(function(result){
               yearly.push(result.data); //here you will add your new value to yearly array
               return result.data; //you are returning new data after you stored it in yearly variable
             });

            }   
        }
    };  /*Return Ends*/
});
```

Please share your feedback with us.

Comment: but if i call this service then again http request is made. thats why i have an yearly = [] . so that incase if service is called again then already stored data in an array is returned instead of calling the server again.

Comment: someService.getYearlyAgg().then(function(){  }); gets the job done temporrily for now.

Comment: someService.getYearlyAgg().then(function(){});  is the right way to call your this service in your controller.

Comment: If you are sattisfied with my answer please mark it as correct answer.